# Como gerar com while ou do-while várias Iterações em um ArrayList de um conjunto de dados?

Tags: java, arraylist

Tenho o seguinte conjunto de dados em um arraylist.

```
Conference,Conference,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,true,1.0, 01,6.0
Reviewer,Reviewer,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,false,1.0, 01,6.0
Review,Review,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,true,1.0, 01,6.0
Person,Person,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,true,1.0, 01,6.0
Paper,Paper,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,false,1.0, 01,6.0
ProgramCommittee,Program_committee,0.98,0.75,0.81,1.0,1.0,1.0,true,1.0, 01,5.54
ProgramCommitteeMember,Committee_member,0.81,0.62,0.57,1.0,1.0,1.0,false,1.0, 21,5.0
Co-author,Contribution_co-author,0.63,0.62,0.57,1.0,1.0,1.0,true,1.0, 21,4.82
Preference,Review_preference,0.6,0.42,0.58,1.0,1.0,1.0,true,1.0, 21,4.6
```

Preciso gerar várias iterações com estes dados.

**Para cada iteração, preciso eliminar a primeira linha da lista e multiplicar todas as outras linhas que tiverem valor `true` por 1.1 e aquelas que tiverem valor `false` por 0.9 as iterações devem ter o mesmo número de linhas da lista.**

A princípio, compreendi que deveria criar um ArrayList da Classe Java abaixo:

```
public class Candidatas {

public String entidade1;
public String entidade2;
public double m1;
public double m2;
public double m3;
public double m4;
public double m5;
public double m6;
public String tipo;
public double mm;
public String id;
public double mm1;


public String getEntidade1() {
return entidade1;
}

public void setEntidade1(String entidade1) {
this.entidade1 = entidade1;
} 

public String getEntidade2() {
return entidade2;
}

public void setEntidade2(String entidade2) {
this.entidade2 = entidade2;
}

public double getM1() {
return m1;
}

public void setM1(double m1) {
this.m1 = m1;
}

public double getM2() {
return m2;
}

public void setM2(double m2) {
this.m2 = m2;
}

public double getM3() {
return m3;
}

public void setM3(double m3) { 
this.m3 = m3;
} 
public double getM4() {
return m4;
}

public void setM4(double m4) {
this.m4 = m4;
}

public double getM5() {
return m5;
}

public void setM5(double m5) {
this.m5 = m5;
}

public double getM6() {
return m6;
}

public void setM6(double m6) {
this.m6 = m6;
}

public String getTipo() {
return tipo;
}

public void setTipo(String tipo) {
this.tipo = tipo;
} 

public double getMm() {
return mm;
}

public void setMm(double mm) {
this.mm = mm;
}

public String getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
this.id = id;
}

public double getMm1() {
return mm1;
}

public void setMm1(double mm1) {
this.mm1 = mm1; 
 }

}
```

Comment: Sim, no final a lista vai estar vazia. A quantidade de iterações será igual a quantidade de linhas do conjunto de dados. Mas para cada iteração, vou ter que multiplicar os valores nas  linhas que tiverem true por 1.1 e aquelas que tiverem false por 0.9.

Comment: o resultado vai parecer nas iterações.

Comment: Olá! Compartilhe conosco o código que já tentou fazer para resolver o problema

Answer (score 0):

Está difícil de entender a pergunta, aqui uma tentativa de reponder a pergunta: "como iterar uma Lista usando `while` ou `do-while`?".

Assumindo que temos uma class ConjuntoDados, o método para iterar uma lista com instâncias dessa classe ficaria:

```
void iterarConjuntoDados(List<ConjuntoDados> lista) {
    Iterator<ConjuntoDados> iterator = lista.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        ConjuntoDados conjuntoDados = iterator.next();
        // faz o que tiver que ser feito com conjuntoDados
    }
}
```

O `do-while` não é aconselhável nesse caso pois irá executar a iteração **antes** do teste de continuação do laço. Nesse caso teriamos que fazer um teste adicional no ínicio do laço para testar se não chegamos no fim da lista.

Comment: É porque preciso ter a quantidade de iterações igual ao tamanho da lista. Só consegui gerar apenas uma iteração com o For.

Comment: E para cada iteração o programa deve multiplicar os resultados das iterações anteriores por 0.9 se a linha for false ou por 1.1 se a linha for true. Ele vai realizando as iterações e multiplicando por 1.1 ou por 0.9 até a lista inicial ficar vazia e no final restar apenas todas as iterações.